# conversion of pdf file to word document using itext in java

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Thanks for reply. Text is coming but not considering any (spaces, font sizes, side headings,body). I want to read the data from pdf exactly what exists in it.Any help Appreciated. my code is given below

Here is my code so far:

```
package bis.proj.samp;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor;
import com.lowagie.text.Document;
import com.lowagie.text.Paragraph;
import com.lowagie.text.rtf.RtfWriter2;

public class ReadPdfFile {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        Document document = new Document();

        File  file = new File("/home/mujafar/Desktop/file.doc");
        if(!file.exists())
            file.createNewFile();

        RtfWriter2.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("/home/mujafar/Desktop/file.doc"));
        System.out.println("file created");
        document.open();

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("/home/mujafar/Desktop/NPTEL Transcription Guidelines.pdf");
    int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
    System.out.println("total no of pages:::"+n);
    String s="";
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {

        s=PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, i);


        System.out.println("string:::"+s);
        System.out.println("====================");

        document.add(new Paragraph(s));
        document.newPage();
    }
    document.close();
    System.out.println("completed");
    } catch (Exception de) {}
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better to use a RenderListener, like so:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputStream);
StringBuilder documentText = new StringBuilder();
RenderListener listener = new RenderListener()
{
    @Override
    public void renderText(TextRenderInfo arg0)
    {
        LineSegment segment = arg0.getBaseline();
        int x = (int)segment.getStartPoint().get(Vector.I1);
        int y = (int)segment.getStartPoint().get(Vector.I2);
        b.append("at "+x+"/"+y+": "+arg0.arg0.getText());
        b.append("\n");
    }

    @Override
    public void renderImage(ImageRenderInfo arg0)
    {
        // TODO
    }

    @Override
    public void endTextBlock()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void beginTextBlock()
    {
    }
};

PdfReaderContentParser p = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++)
{
    p.processContent(i, listener);
    b.append("\n\n(page break)\n\n");
}

// b now contains the accumulated text from your PDF.
// You could use Apache Poi to construct a DOCX with it.
System.out.println(b.toString());
```

Note that the renderText calls are not necessarily in the order in which they appear on the screen/paper, you may need to "reconstruct" the page layout based on the X/Y coordinates in the various arg0 objects.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But I didn't understand how to use the above code.Could you please attach the complete code to read the content(text and images) from pdf file and write the content to word document(doc/docx).

Comment: The above is only to get the text, as this is what I thought you required. I will edit it to make it more complete. Images and layout are left as an exercise. The RenderListener also has a renderImage() method.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Text is coming but not considering any (spaces, font sizes, side headings,body). I want to read the data from pdf exactly what exists in it.Any help Appreciated. my code is given below